# Does the weapon level increase the performance of the weapon?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Does the weapon level increase the performance of the weapon (accuracy, damage, etc), or is it only used to determine what perks and attachments are available for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can increase the performance of the weapon **through** weapon proficiencies (weapon perks), but there are no passive bonuses based on weapon level.

Answer (score 2):

It's only used to determine what proficiencies, attachments, and camo you can equip on it. So in a way, yes it can make your gun do more damage and be more accurate, but it depends on what you equip